# @OnClick array with optional ids (ButterKnife)

Tags: android, onclick, option-type, butterknife

I have an activity that inflates a view when a web request finished.
Some of the widgets of this view have to be attached to one `onClick` method, so I have:

```
@OnClick({R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2, R.id.inflated_bt1, R.id.inflated_bt2})
public void onClick(View view) {
    // ...
}
```

As `R.id.inflated_bt1` and `R.id.inflated_bt2` don't exist when the app is created, it throws an exception suggesting to set an `@Optional` annotation.

> Required view 'inflated_bt1' with ID XXXXXXXX for method 'onClick' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Optional' annotation.

Is there a way to set some of the views with the `@Optional` annotation and inject them when the view is inflated? Or, is there another way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

<strike>The correct answer is to use the `@Nullable` annotation.</strike> See the [Butterknife home page](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). <strike>Usage example:</strike>

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

@Nullable
@OnClick(R.id.maybe_missing)
void onMaybeMissingClicked() {
    // TODO ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the year since I wrote this answer and it was accepted, the **Butterknife docs changed**, and the current preferred method for accomplishing this is to use the `@Optional` annotation. Since this is the accepted answer, I feel it important to update it to address current practice. For example:

```
import butterknife.Optional;

@Optional
@OnClick(R.id.maybe_missing)
void onMaybeMissingClicked() {
    // TODO ...
}
```

Comment: According to the ButterKnife github page, `add a @Nullable annotation to fields or the @Optional annotation to methods` http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @TheoKanning Did you seriously downvote my answer? The docs changed. There wasn't an `Optional` when I answered this _over a year ago_. If the answer needs updating, update it!

Answer (score 46):

Just add `@Optional` annotation on the top of your method as is shown in the code below:

```
@Optional
@OnClick({R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2, R.id.inflated_bt1, R.id.inflated_bt2})
public void onClick(View view) {
    // ...
}
```

There is a case where you don't have `R.id.inflated_bt1` in the layout xml which you use on your `Activity`. For case like this you have to use `@Optional` annotation.

When you use only `@OnClick` annotation in `YourClass$$ViewInjector` source code looks like below:

```
view = finder.findRequiredView(source, 2131230789, "method 'onClick'");
view.setOnClickListener(
  new butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener() {
    @Override public void doClick(
      android.view.View p0
    ) {
      target.onClick();
    }
  });
```

and the method `findRequiredView` throws `IllegalStateException` when view is `null`.

But when you use additionally `@Optional` annotation, generated code looks like below

```
view = finder.findOptionalView(source, 2131230789);
if (view != null) {
  view.setOnClickListener(
    new butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener() {
      @Override public void doClick(
        android.view.View p0
      ) {
        target.onClick();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I use ButterKnife.Finder?
JavaDoc shows a "DO NOT USE" message, and I cannot create it:
"cannot inherit from final class butterknife.ButterKnife.Finder"

Comment: Why do you want to use thus class ?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Nullable
@OnClick({R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2, R.id.inflated_bt1, R.id.inflated_bt2})
public void onClick(View view) {
    // ...
}
```

If you include nullable as said by Butterknife docs and also by @AutonomousApps then you can include as may as ids even though you are not using them all the time.

Remember to include annotation support library if you are not using appcompact library. Check this link [Support Annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations)